# Vercel PKG: Executable Not Working Outside Of The /dist Folder

Tags: linux, windows, npm, executable, vercel

Good day,

I would like to make an executable to open [Playwright's codegen](https://playwright.dev/docs/codegen) windows for my not-tech-savvy coworkers. They are all working on Windows.

For this project I'm using PKG from Vercel https://github.com/vercel/pkg

So I'm trying to package this super simple application: https://github.com/RilDev/e2e-codegen

But:

- on Linux, the executable works only when it is launched from within the `/dist` folder. If I move it elsewhere on my system, it stops working.
- on Windows, the same thing happens, even when I try to copy manually all missing dependencies in the `/dist` folder.

Do you have any idea to make this POC work?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What error you are getting? Also, the build that you have created must have all the required packages added while building the binary.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

I had to add node_modules in assets.

```
"pkg": {
  "assets": [
    "/node_modules/**/*",
      "/dist/**/*",
      ...
  ],
  "output": "output.exe",
  "targets": [
    "node18-win-x64"
  ]
}
```